# Groovy: compiler error: exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, groovy

I have configured lombok in eclipse for my project. i am getting below error on my groovy class file package when i import  **import lombok.ToString**

**Error:**
    Groovy: compiler error: exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit

[image]

Comment: why do you need lombok for groovy classes?

Comment: Can you look in your Error Log view and grab the stack trace associated with this error?

Comment: i have added screenshot it is giving error at package level. lombok is required for other files.